# How to read Postgres TIMESTAMPTZ as .NET Core DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I can't find a way how to read a postgres timestamptz as a .NET DateTimeOffset value. According to the documentation it seems to be possible. Could someone describe how to handle this issue.

I'm using:
Postgres: 11.x
Npgsql: 4.1.0

The code snippet is extremely simple:

```cs
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02'::timestamptz";
        var o = (DateTimeOffset)command.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}
```

It throws an invalid cast exception from DateTime to DateTimeOffset:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.DateTimeOffset'
```

Comment: Try to use parameters something like "SELECT @param". Create a DateTimeOffset C# value and assign it to the parameter.

Comment: `DateTimeOffset` was introduced in .NET 3.5 and Npgsql was still supporting .NET 2.0 so `timestamptz` was returned as `DateTime`. Although `DateTimeOffset` was later back-ported to .NET 2.0 SP1, they decided not to introduce a breaking change by changing how it was returned. See: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/11#issuecomment-52108841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a `DateTime` value is read by `command.ExecuteScalar()`. There's the reader method `GetFieldValue<T>()` to get a `DateTimeOffset` value. That's not suitable for me at the moment but a possible workaround.

More details: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2641